Output the 97th ASCII character (or "a") without using strings and numbers
Side note
If this question contains something copied from some other question. This is definitely not my fault since i didn't knew the question existed
Back to the question
The challenge is simple.
Make a program or function that outputs or returns the letter a (the 97th character of the ASCII table) without numbers and litteral strings in your code. You cannot for example have 97 or "a" or 'a' in your code or any other number or litteral string.
Languages that doesn't have any numbers and/or string instruction (like brainfuck) is also allowed. This explanation might be not understandable, but it's the best i can do
Anyways. Good luck

Google Sheets, 15 bytes
This gets the 97th character in the ASCII table:
=char(row(A97))

The A97 in the formula is not a literal string nor the number 97 but a cell reference. If the question is interpreted to mean that such cell reference is not allowed either, put this sorter version in cell A97 instead (12 bytes):
=char(row())

To do the same with math (48 bytes):
=let(a,len(false),b,a/a,c,b+b+b,char(a^c-a*a-c))

Alternatively, this gets the 65th character in the ASCII table ("A") and converts it to lowercase (39 bytes):
=lower(mid(false,pi()-n(true),n(true)))

The output of these four formulas is currently the same, but that may change in the event ITU-T Recommendation T.50 IRA gets updated or replaced, and the implementation of Google Sheets char() function follows through.
Thanks to General Grievance.

On the right track, I think. =LOWER(CHAR(LET(a,LEN(TRUE),a*a*a+a/a))) - 40

Or just shove =CHAR(ROW()) into A97.

@GeneralGrievance that's... creative.

but it doesn't follow the rules of the question. Because 97 is a number

@Gleb 97 is indeed a number, but A97 is a cell reference. For example, A97 + 1 isn't 98 in the general case. In my opinion, saying that A97 is a number would be similar to saying that char() is a string literal.

Oh okay then. Thanks for a lesson on Google sheets

How dare you fuck the brain, 38 bytes
II+=+=+=+=+=+^II=+=+=+^II=+=+=+v+v+IPH

Try it online!
